# How to implement onClickListener only when is image click?

Tags: android-imageview, onclicklistener, android-custom-view

I have image like pieces of pizza, and I want implement onClickListener only when I click on pizza?

Answer (score -1):

```
pizzaImageView.setClickable(true);
pizzaImageView.setOnClickListener(pizzaClickListener);
private OnClickListener pizzaClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view){
//Do code here
   }
};
```

Comment: I know for that..but trik is thet I want to get Event only when I click image, no when I click on whole Layout, only when I click on image.