# How To Make Pieces Of Pizza Buttons Clickable?

Tags: android, button

[image: pieces of pizza are clickable]

Hi, I want to make a menu with this style, but I have no idea if this is possible or not!

I have searched on the Internet, but all I found was just this question that wasn't helpful:
[How to implement onClickListener only when is image click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315610/how-to-implement-onclicklistener-only-when-is-image-click)

Answer (score 0):

Call `performClick()` method in `onTouchEvent` of your custom view. You have to implement `TouchListener`. And don't forget to call `super.onTouchEvent(event)` inside your `onTouchEvent` method.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        return performClick();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Design your layout with 4 ImageView in a RelativeLayout or FrameLayout.
Give every ImageView an ID then define your desired ImageView in Java codes and:

```
ImageView about = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.about);
about .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //YOUR CODES
        }
    });
```